# How do I catch cache for the user in CakePhp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cache-control

I dont really have much experience in cache controlling and CakePhp. I am not a regular programmer as well. I got a situation where if the user is visiting a site for a first time there will be a pop up appearing on the screen. If the user visited it before there wont be any popup.

As for checking the user is authentic, i can use

```
<?php if (empty($auth_user)) { ?>

//codes for popup modal

<?php } ?>
```

My question is, is that possible to implement some logic like this to catch the cache or check wheather the tmp file is empty or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is not good ways to catch cache, But there only one way `COOKIES` to do it but it will be terminated and work newly as user just delete them in his browser.

**As php is an server side scripting language**
If you not want to save cookie then use `LOCALSTORAGE` but in `JAVASCRIPT`
1.**COOKIE**(Cookies can be stored via `PHP`)

```
setcookie(nameOfCookie, valueOfCookie, expireTimeOfCookie, pathOfCookie);
```

*Simple insert "/" in pathOfCookie* 
Getting **COOKIE** in `PHP`

```
<?php
if(isset($_COOKIE[$nameOfCookie])) {
    //User already visited your site.
} else {
   //Use doesn't visited your site yet.
   //Show POPUP here. And set cookie here (In Else Condition).
}
?>
```

> Keep in mind that if the expiryTimeOfCookie passes it will expiry. And not exist (Time In Seconds For 1 Day = 86400